# Correlated Subquery (on same table)

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I have a table that keeps up with device state changes in a room, and need to write a query that lists the amount of time since the last state change.  The table consists of the fields, new_state, prev_state, room, timestamp.  My latest try was

```
SELECT a.room, a.prev_state, a.new_state, 
timediff(a.timestamp, b.timestamp) from   status_change as a
(SELECT b.timestamp from status_change as b 
 WHERE a.timestamp<b.timestamp and a.room=b.room
 ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Hopefully that conveys what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Comment: What is the `Primary Key` for `status_change` table?

Comment: the status_change doesn't have a primary key.  If I were going to add one it would be room,timestamp - which would be a unique key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (and you should put a primary key on it, especially for performance reasons)

```
SELECT status_change.*
 , previous.timestamp AS earlier_timestampe
 , TIMEDIFF(status_change.timestamp, previous.timestamp) AS time_between
FROM status_change 
LEFT JOIN status_change AS previous
  ON status_change.room = previous.room
    AND status_change.timestamp > previous.timestamp
LEFT JOIN status_change AS inbetweener
  ON status_change.room = inbetweener.room
    AND inbetweener.timestamp BETWEEN previous.timestamp AND status_change.timestamp
WHERE inbetweener.room IS NULL
ORDER BY status_change.timestamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.timestamp-t1.timestamp 
FROM state_change AS t1 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM state_change) AS t2 
ON t1.new_state = t2.prev_state AND t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
```

Comment: What I need is the delta between the rows.  For example if row 1 had a timestamp of 13:00 and row 2 had a timestamp of 14:00  - I need a query that will list all rows with the amount of time since the last entry.  So in the example the query would produce row 2 information and a timediff of 1:00 (that would be 14:00 minus 13:00).  Hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: Does the new state get saved into a new row? resulting in the previous' row's new_state being the new row's prev_state ?

Comment: See updated answer. I worked this out blindly, hope you get the idea. I'll be pleased with feedback though :)

Comment: I tried it - thanks.  I think the problem is that the join produces all the previous rows that meet the condition rather than just the 1 previous row.  (I narrowed a query to just one day and one room and it returned 7,266 rows where I was wanting just 4).  We were able to get what we needed using the rownum feature.  I'll post the query we came up with in the next comment.  Thanks for helping me think this through.  It was a brain cramper for me!

Comment: select t1.room,t2.timestamp as time_row1,t2.prev_state,t2.new_state,timediff(t2.timestamp,t1.timestamp) as diff_bwt_rows,t1.timestamp as time_row2 from 
(select room,prev_state,new_state,timestamp,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum1 from status_change, (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS foo
order by room,timestamp desc) t1,(select roombed_fk,prev_state,new_state,timestamp,@i:=@i+1 as rownum2 from status_change, (SELECT @i:=0) AS foo
order by room,timestamp desc) t2
where  t1.room=t2.room and t1.rownum1=t2.rownum2+1 and date(t2.timestamp)="2013/11/21" ;

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the queries that are offered, I would strongly suggest adding a simple trigger based on the add of each new entry per device.  Basically two columns lastUpdateID, UpdateIDBeforeThat.

Then in your update trigger, do something like

```
update RoomTable
   set UpdateIDBeforeThat = lastUpdateID,
       lastUpdateID = newIDJustInserted
   where
      room = RoomBasedOnInsertedRecord
     and currentRoomStatus != InsertedRecordRoomStatus
```

Then, your query to compare could be as simple as
select

```
select
      r.roomid,
      c1.date/time,
      c2.date/time,
      calc-diff of date/time,
      any other fields from c1 or c2 respectively
   FROM 
      rooms r
         LEFT JOIN status_change c1
            on r.lastUpdateID = c1.ID
         left join status_change c2
            on r.UpdateBeforeThat = c2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks - a colleague also suggested the use of rownum - are you aware of any problems with that approach?

Comment: @user3466409, don't know about rownum, but if via an auto-increment column in your status_change table, that should ensure valid link by the actual key.